# Shirt Order program

Tags: python

this is my code for a small task in Microsoft's Python course. I looked through their forums but none of the discussion pages were of much help.

[image: The task]

What I'm confused about is why my end *if* statement doesn't run and I'm not sure how Booleans work and why I have to set available to False for it to work, and then set the rest to True. Why can't I just set available to True?

And, how can I code this in a more succinct manner?

```
#variable inputs
colour = input("What colour shirt? " ).lower()
size = input("What size? " ).lower()

#why do i set available to False?
available = False


if colour == "white":
    available == True
    if size == "m" or size == "l":
        available == True
        print("Available")

    else:
        print("Unavailable")

elif colour == "blue":
    available == True

    if size == "s" or size == "m":
        available == True
        print("Available")

    else:
        print("Unavailable")

else:
    print("Nope")

#why doesn't this run?
if colour and size == available:
    output = print("The", colour, "shirt is available in", size)
    print(output)
```

Comment: Because you're using `available == True` to assign the value. Should be `available = True`. You set it to `False` (correctly) at the beginning because you don't know if it is available, and only set it to `True` when you've established that it is.

Comment: You also try to set it to `True` twice each time, once after the colour check and once after the size check. That can't be correct.

Comment: Instead of setting `available = False` at the beginning of your code, you could also set it to False in the `Else: Print('Nope')` section. It's a matter of personal preference. I think I prefer putting it in the Else myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of simple changes will make it work.

1. Change `available == True` to `available = True` - first is comparison, second is assignment.
2. `if colour and size == available:` isn't correct. `colour` and `size` are the inputs. You only have one `available` variable and that's either `True` or `False`. This is enough for you to check if it's available for that `colour` and `size`.

```
#variable inputs
colour = input("What colour shirt? " ).lower()
size = input("What size? " ).lower()

#why do i set available to False?
available = False


if colour == "white":
    if size == "m" or size == "l":
        available = True
        print("Available")

    else:
        print("Unavailable")

elif colour == "blue":
    if size == "s" or size == "m":
        available = True
        print("Available")

    else:
        print("Unavailable")

else:
    print("Nope")

#why doesn't this run?
if available:    
    output = print("The", colour, "shirt is available in", size)
    print(output)
```

You asked about why you set `available` to `False` at the start. This is a pretty common way of working with logic. You start off, in this case, assuming that `available` is `False`. A reasonable assumption as there are far more colour and size options that are not available than those that are. You then check to see if it's actually `True` and, if so, you change it to `True` when you know that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a more succinct way:

```
colour = input("What colour shirt?").lower()
size = input("What size? ").lower()

available = False

'''
First we filter out non blue or white shirts
'''
if colour == 'white' or colour == 'blue':
    '''
    Now we get the right sizes
    '''
    if colour == 'white' and size == 'l' or size == 'm':
        available = True
        print('shirt is available')
        print('order is confirmed')
    elif colour == 'blue' and size == 'm' or size == 's':
        available = True
        print('shirt is available')
        print('order is confirmed')
    else:
        print('Sorry, that shirt is unavailable')
else:
    print('Sorry, that shirt is unavailable')
```

And for your other questions and original code:

```
#variable inputs
colour = input("What colour shirt? " ).lower()
size = input("What size? " ).lower()

#why do i set available to False?
'''
You want to set this to false because you're only going to say a shirt is available when it is.
This way you can't 'forget' to say to you don't have it in stock. It's a safe guard in logic.
'''
available = False


if colour == "white":
    available == True
    if size == "m" or size == "l":
        available == True
        print("Available")

    else:
        print("Unavailable")

elif colour == "blue":
    available == True

    if size == "s" or size == "m":
        available == True
        print("Available")

    else:
        print("Unavailable")

else:
    print("Nope")

#why doesn't this run?
'''
This if block isn't being run because the colour and size variables are strings, 
they aren't changed to mean True or False so the if never returns true.
'''
if colour and size == available:
    output = print("The", colour, "shirt is available in", size)
    print(output)
```

That's a real common and easy way to keep you isValid or isTrue variable correct. You'll find lots of places where that will help you out. Also it's a good idea to see if you can write conditions in smaller chuncks or group similar ones together. That will help increase code readability and sanity checks when you read it out loud or back to yourself. Hope this can help!